# update data and image using 1 button, error data not update if insert same data in combobox

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

no update if same data combobox

```
            Cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_image where [Nama Barang]= @Nama_Barang  ", Conn)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama_Barang", ComboBox1.Text)
                RD = Cmd.ExecuteReader
                RD.Read()
                If RD.HasRows Then
                    Call Koneksi()



                Dim edit As String = "Update tbl_image set Jumlah = @jumlah, [Stok Barang] =@Stok_Barang, Gambar = @Gambar where Kode = @Kode or [Nama Barang] = @Nama_Barang "


                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kode", TextBox1.Text)
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama_Barang", ComboBox1.Text)
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jumlah", TextBox2.Text)
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stok_Barang", TextBox3.Text)

                Dim Images As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@Gambar", SqlDbType.Image)
                Images.Value = Dgambar
                Cmd.Parameters.Add(Images)

                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


                'MsgBox("Data Berhasil Di Update")
                    'cmd.Dispose()


                Else

                Dim simpan As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_image VALUES(  @Kode,@Nama_Barang, @Jumlah, @Stok_Barang, @Gambar) "
                'Dim simpan As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_image VALUES(  '" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "', @Gambar) "
                Cmd = New SqlCommand(simpan, Conn)
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kode", TextBox1.Text)
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama_Barang", ComboBox1.Text)
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jumlah", TextBox2.Text)
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stok_Barang", TextBox3.Text)
                Dim MemoryStream As New MemoryStream
                PictureBox1.Image.Save(MemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
                Dim Dgambar As Byte() = MemoryStream.GetBuffer
                Dim Images As New SqlParameter("@Gambar", SqlDbType.Image)
                Images.Value = Dgambar
                Cmd.Parameters.Add(Images)
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Data Berhasil Di Simpan")
```

Dim edit As String = "Update tbl_image set Jumlah = @jumlah, [Stok Barang] =@Stok_Barang, Gambar = @Gambar where Kode = @Kode or [Nama Barang] = @Nama_Barang "

Comment: What is the Primary Key of tbl_image?

Comment: Primary Key of tbl_image is Kode